# ResultOfStringPassedToVerb equals does not consider String before should

Tags: scala, scalatest

In the below code comparison of two logically equal ResultOfStringPassedToVerb instances, should print

> both are equal

but it prints

> both are different

```
package msgs

import org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import org.scalatest.words.ResultOfStringPassedToVerb

/**
  * Created by mogli on 9/1/17.
  */
object FlatSpecMsgs extends FlatSpecLike {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val m1: ResultOfStringPassedToVerb = "a" should "b"
    val m2 = "a" should "b"

//    println(m1)
//    println(m2)

    if (m1.equals(m2)) {
      println("both are equal")
    } else {
      println("both are different")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ResultOfStringPassedToVerb` class doesn't override the `equals` method for comparison, so the `equals` or `==` (In **Scala** , `==` is equal to `equals` method) method is comparing the `m1` and `m2`'s **reference address**, since they are 2 objects, the **reference addresses** should not be same, so `equals` method return `false`.

You can find more details from **Java**'s `equals` method:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-